# How To Edit Tableview Cell Data with Core Data In Another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, tableview

I have a `tableview` that has data stored in `core data` and when the `tableviewCell` is tapped it opens another `viewController` with a `label` with the data on it. I want to have a `textfield` and a `button` on that `viewController` that when the `button` is tapped it updates the `tableviewCell` data and saves in `core data`.

Here is some code when I pass the data over
`Main View Controller`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    var name2 = String()

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    let name = itemName[indexPath.row]
    name2 = (name.value(forKey: "title") as? String)!

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let secondVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "secondView") as! SecondViewController
    secondVC.name = name2
    self.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Here is in the other view  controller

```
var name = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    nameLabel.text = name

}
```

Now all I need is to be able to edit one of those `tableviewCells` from the `second view controller` and send it into the `tableview` in the first and update `core data`.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to save your data in second view controller to core data and fetch the same in first view controller and display in the table.